# Does Essence loss still drain Resonance in 6th world?

Tags: character-creation, shadowrun-6th-world

In earlier editions, Technomancers avoided augmentation because essence loss cost them resonance, too. Reading through the 6th world core book, I can find no reference to this, although the example technomancer has kept his essence at 6.

So, what is it? Is it called out anywhere specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, the character still suffers loss of Resonance.**

As of today, the 6th Edition Core rulebook states on pg. 38, under the heading "Essence":

> specifically, anytime your Essence goes below any whole integer, you lose a corresponding point of Magic or Resonance

The edition I have includes all errata applied<strike>, but looking over the errata this passage has been in there since release, so if you have a first-print hard copy, you should be able to find it</strike>. It appears to be missing from the first run print, unfortunately.

Comment: Where exactly do I get the errata? There is no link in the book as far as I can tell. Definitely not happy with this book for how much errata it seems to need to be functional...

Comment: @WeckarE. you can find it on the Shadowrun Sixth World website: https://www.shadowrunsixthworld.com/resources/

Comment: @WeckarE. Were you able to find it in the book by any chance? I'm curious if you're using the first run print, and if it was in there.

Comment: It's not there in my book. The relevant sentence is there, but ends after Magic. The whole Essence heading does not mention Resonance or Technomancers. It is exactly where I would have expected to find it.